# Get drop-down menu displaying right in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, html-select

Well, here's my problem. I've created a very simple drop-down menu form, using JavaScript and HTML (and of course the internet). It opens up a page in the frame located below, which works perfectly in Chrome. It does work in Internet Explorer, but if you select an option lower in the list, close the menu and re-open it, the options "float" over the form.

```
<form action="../cgi-bin/redirect.pl" 
method=post onSubmit="return dropdown(this.selection)"
target="Frame2">

<select name="selection"> 
<option value="">Choose an option:
<option value="2012-2013.html">2012/2013
<option value="2011-2012.html">2011/2012
<option value="2010-2011.html">2010/2011
<option value="2009-2010.html">2009/2010
</select>
<input type=submit value="Choose">
</form>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
function dropdown(mySel){
var myWin, myVal;
myVal = mySel.options[mySel.selectedIndex].value;
if(myVal) {
if(mySel.form.target)myWin = parent[mySel.form.target];
else myWin = window;
if (! myWin) return true;
myWin.location = myVal; }
return false;}
```

As you can see in [this](http://oi43.tinypic.com/25p30vs.jpg) image, it functions as it should in Google Chrome. But not in [Internet Explorer](http://oi42.tinypic.com/121wytv.jpg)
, and a lot of people still use that browser. I don't really need these fancy CSS menu's there are today, this is more than good enough. My question is: is there a solution to display the dropdownmenu in IE like it's displayed in Chrome?

I've already tried to set classes to the form, select and option tags to set the top of them, but that didn't solve the problem for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what versions of IE you're seeing this issue with, but in IE11 it not only floats over form but over the IE window itself. It appears to be the default behavior of IE. You're question (to illustrate this problem) can be stripped of its js since your question is about what happens BEFORE the post. I can replicate your question with the simplified html here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
    <select name="selection"> 
        <option value="">Choose an option:
        <option value="2012-2013.html">2012/2013
        <option value="2011-2012.html">2011/2012
        <option value="2010-2011.html">2010/2011
        <option value="2009-2010.html">2009/2010
    </select>
    <input type=submit value="Choose">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Your scenario is an edge case that i personally wouldn't worry about. Most people aren't using IE, and most people won't re-select an option. If they do, they're use to seeing IE dropdowns behave this way.

Here's a snapshot of Yahoo's sign up page. I've selected December in the month dropdown and re-selected it. Their dropdown behaves in the same way in IE (as does yours):
http://tinypic.com/r/1qh1si/5

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm indeed using Internet Explorer 11, and it floats over the Internet Explorer window itself as well. So basically, this is just a weird IE-behavior and there is no way and no need to modify it?

Comment: Correct. The IE11 devs apparently want it this way despite every other browser behaving differently.